# Подмена контента на сайте. Не осуществляется поиск на основе встречаемого слова в целой фразе

Tags: php

Есть простой скрипт:

```
<?php

$utm = $_GET['utm_term'];

if ($utm == 'слово') {
    $multiTitle = 'Заголовок';
} elseif($utm == 'слово2') {
    $multiTitle = 'Заголовок 2';
}

?>
```

При `utm_term=слово` или `utm_term=слово2` скрипт прекрасно работает, но стоит добавить хоть один лишний символ, например: `utm_term=слово_буква`, работать перестает. Как сделать, чтобы скрипт осуществлял поиск на основе встречаемого слова в целой фразе?

Я полный нуб в php, этот скрипт я просто нашел. Я сейчас может чуть подробнее напишу что и для чего. Подмена, как все думаю поняли, осуществляется относительно ключа, по которому зашел человек. В `utm_term` у меня целые ключевые фразы, например: `utm_term=автомобильный_набор_инструментов`. Соответственно, я хочу указать в скрипте искомое слово, в данном случае "автомобильный", после чего скрипт может искать его в целой ключевой фразе, и если находит, то подменяет определенный контент. Искомых слов более 15, каждое из них объединяет группу ключевых фраз.

И было бы замечательно ещё иметь возможность искать по части слова, например "сантех", вместо "сантехнический".

Осталось совсем чутка допилить, как получить возможность использовать HTML теги внутри подмен?

```
<?php
$utm_term = $_GET['utm_term'];
$utm_array = explode("_", mb_strtolower($utm_term));  // Разбиваем текст в массив по знаку "_"
$keywords_array = array(  // Массив, где ключ - ключевые слова, а значения - подмены
    "автомобильный" => "Автомобильный набор инструментов", 
    "сантехнический" => "Сантехнический набор инструментов"
);

foreach ($utm_array as $utm) { // Перебераем $utm
    foreach ($keywords_array as $keyword => $title) {  // Перебираем ключевые слова и подмены
        // Проверяем вхождения $utm в $keyword
        if (!(strripos($keyword, $utm) === false)) {
            $multiTitle = $title;
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Думаю как минимум надо привести сам скрипт поиска, не видя его невозможно сказать в чем проблема

Comment: Извиняюсь. Неправильно добавлял код в описание вопроса, вот он и не отображался.

Comment: Вы хотите спросить: нужны ли мне регулярные выражения?

Comment: Может и нужны, я не секу, к сожалению, в php. Мне бы конкретный пример кода по моему вопросу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию [strripos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strripos.php):

```
<?php
    $utm_term = $_GET['utm_term'];
    $utm_array = explode("_", mb_strtolower($utm_term));  // Разбиваем текст в массив по знаку "_"
    $keywords_array = array(  // Массив, где ключ - ключевые слова, а значения - подмены
        "автомобильный" => "Автомобильный набор инструментов", 
        "сантехнический" => "Сантехнический набор инструментов", 
        "волшебный" => "Автомобильный набор инструментов"
    );

    foreach ($utm_array as $utm) { // Перебераем $utm
        foreach ($keywords_array as $keyword => $title) {  // Перебераем ключевые слова и подмены
            // Проверяем вхождения $utm в $keyword
            if (!(strripos($keyword, $utm) === false)) {
                $multiTitle = $title;
            }
        }
    }
    echo $multiTitle;
```

Comment: Поправил под условие, которое было описано в комментах под другим ответом.

Comment: Я не совсем понял "Результат". Где в скрипте параметр, в котором я буду записывать на что конкретно менять тот или иной контент? 

В приведенном мной начальном примере есть параметр $multiTitle, в котором я записываю подмены, а в html коде в нужном месте прописываю <?php echo $multiTitle; ?>.

Comment: @МаксимГладилин, поправил

Comment: а можно ещё один важный момент уточнить. Искомых слов будет 17 и соответственно 17 подмен. Чтобы все они работали прописывать нужно так?:

$keywords_array = array( 
    "автомобильный", 
);
$multiTitle = 'Автомобильный набор инструментов';

$keywords_array = array( 
    "сантехнический", 
);
$multiTitle = 'Сантехнический набор инструментов';

Comment: Ну у меня 17 групп с ключевыми фразами, каждая группа объединена каким-то общим словом, которые я и хочу прописывать в скрипте. Под каждое такое искомое слово мне нужна будет отдельная подмена. То есть, один человек заходит по ссылке, в которой `utm_term=автомобильный_набор_инструментов` и видит какой-то релевантный заголовок, другой заходит по ссылке с `utm_term=набор_инструментов_в_подарок` и ему выдается другой заголовок. А в скрипте в свою очередь для каждого такого слова (в данном примере, это "автомобильный" и "подарок") прописаны свои подмены.

Comment: @МаксимГладилин, поправил

Comment: блин, как же круто в чём-то реально разбираться) Спасибо тебе ОГРОМНОЕ! Если ещё не задолбал, то один нюанс хотел выяснить. Мне бы хотелось иметь возможность в подменах использовать html теги, так как для некоторых слов в подменах я буду применять другой стиль. Это как-то возможно?

Comment: @MichaelPak, зря вы помогаете лентяям, делая всю работу за них. Но за ответ определенно +.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да, думаю, надо было просто показать, в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, я не далеко не лентяй. Да, у меня нет навыков работы с php, и мне пришлось обратиться за помощью. Если бы все, кто ответил, отвечали как вы, что я ошибся сайтом, вопросов бы не было.

Comment: @МаксимГладилин, вы, увы, ошибаетесь. Помощь и "_сделайте за меня_" это разные вещи. Если бы вы не ленились, и попытались формализовать проблему вы бы смогли наметить путь решения даже без знаний PHP. А уже потом задавать конкретные вопросы

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, очень сложно мне для понимания то, как задавать конкретные вопросы по предмету, из которого ты знаешь только название. Наверно надо хотя бы понимать, о чем спрашивать, чтобы вопросы не звучали " как получить вот такой результат?". Всё действительно проще, вы правы, я ошибся сайтом.

Comment: @MichaelPak, я вам очень благодарен. Судя по всему, вы вполне могли меня послать куда подальше, после моих комментариев на ваш первый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно также используя `preg_match`. Точнее, наверно даже нужно использовать именно её.

```
//$utm = $_GET['utm_term'];
$utm = "слово_буква"; // например   
$find = "/слово/iU"; // i - независимо от регистра | U - кодировка UTF-8
if (preg_match($find, $utm))
{
    echo "найдено 'слово'";
} else {
    echo "не найдено";
}
```

Comment: Я полный нуб в php, тот скрипт я просто нашел. Я сейчас может чуть подробнее напишу что и для чего. 

Подмена, как все думаю поняли, осуществляется относительно ключа, по которому зашел человек. В utm_term у меня целые ключевые фразы, например: utm_term=автомобильный_набор_инструментов. Соответственно, я хочу указать в скрипте искомое слово, в данном случае "автомобильный", после чего скрипт может искать его в целой ключевой фразе, и если находит, то подменяет определенный контент. Искомых слов более 15, каждое из них объединяет группу ключевых фраз.

Comment: И было бы замечательно ещё иметь возможность искать по части слова, например "сантех", вместо "сантехнический".